# Loading multiple WebViews

Tags: android, webview

I have a ViewPager that holds few WebViews, each one loads a pretty heavy web page (it can take up to 10 seconds to load).
I load each WebView linearly (when No.1 finishes No.2 starts and so on).
The problem is that all WebViews run on a single thread (WebViewCoreThread) causing the ones already loaded unresponsive to touches until all others are loaded.

Example with 2 WebViews:

- WebView1 starts loading
- WebView1 finishes loading
- Webview2 starts loading > WebView1 is **unresponsive** to touches
- WebView2 finishes loading > WebView1 is **responsive** to touches

Any idea how to come around this issue?

EDIT:
The problem seems to apply only to javacript as I can scroll inside the unresponsive WebView but not touch on components.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to request focus on the webview, for example when you it is in view:

```
    if (!thisWebView.hasFocus()) {
        thisWebView.requestFocus();
    }
```